# tcpdf library html rendering is too slow

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf (version 5.9.161). `writeHtml()` only renders a html table in my code. If the table is only for one pdf page then it works fine, but if table is big like for 60 pages then it will take up to 100-110 Sec. A php script makes this html in 2-3 sec.

php.ini:

```
Max Execution Time 300 sec
memory limit 128MB
```

My Code is:

```
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);        
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array( PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '',PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN ));
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);   
$pdf->SetFontSubsetting(false);        
$pdf->SetHeaderData(K_PATH_IMAGES.'alpha.png', PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH,'BSS Tech', '');        
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true);     
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 30);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(true);        
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
ob_clean();
$pdf->Output("report.pdf", 'I'); // finalizing pdf document
```

and HTML, NOT USING any kind of css

This table use to Display at least 600 Record in pdf

```
 $html .= ' <div style="text-align: center;"> 
    <table   border="0"  cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
    <tr >
    <th align="left" style="width:120px;font-weight:bold" >Organization Name:</th>
    <th align="left">' . $OrgName . '</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:100px;font-weight:bold">Field :</th>
    <th align="left" >' . $fieldName . '</th>
    </tr>

    <tr >
    <th align="left" style="width:120px;font-weight:bold">Component:</th>
    <th align="left" >' . $type . '</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:100px;font-weight:bold"></th>
    <th align="left"  >' . '' . '</th></tr>

    </tbody></table></div>';


    $html .= ' <div style="text-align: center;"> 
    <table   border=".5"  cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
    <tr >
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:5%;font-weight:bold" >SI#:</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:13%;font-weight:bold" >CP Component</th>
    <th align="left"  BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold">Component ID :</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:10%;font-weight:bold">Circuit No</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8"  style="width:12%;font-weight:bold">Location</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold">Over All Status</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold">Remark</th>
    <th align="left" BGCOLOR="#DBFEF8" style="width:15%;font-weight:bold">Date</th>
    </tr>';

    for ($i=0 ; $i<count($clientID);$i++){
    $html .= '  
    <tr >
    <th align="left"  style="width:5%;">'.($i+1).'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:13%;">'.$clientID[$i]['Type'].'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:15%;">'.$clientID[$i]['ComponentID'].'</th>
     <th align="left"  style="width:10%;">'.$clientID[$i]['CircuitLabel'].'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:12%;">'.$clientID[$i]['Location'].'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:15%;">'.$clientID[$i]['OverAllStatus'].'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:15%;">'.$clientID[$i]['FieldObservation'].'</th>
    <th align="left"  style="width:15%;">'.$clientID[$i]['SurveyDate'].'</th>
    </tr>';
    }

    $html .= '</tbody></table></div>';       
    }
```

Comment: @PhpFreak application was developed with tcpdf ..

Comment: What if you skip the header image? You'll have to figure out which part of your script is making it very slow. And what if you increase the memory limit?

Comment: @Stephan Vierkant tried remove all header content but nothing improvement .....

Comment: There are two table tags inside a unique variable.
Try to use different variable. Also try to use `$pdf->writeHTMLCell()` and see if it gets better.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the memory limit? BTW: 2-3 sec to render the normal HTML page is very slow as well. How are you measuring?

Comment: finally i am using tcpdf cell for creating table.....:(